# Limit number of rows in Crystal Report down then across per column

Tags: crystal-reports, multicol

The `Down then Across` doesn't limit the number of rows down, is there any formula to achieve this? I can adjust the footer height to limit the row numbers, but it's not a good way I suppose to do. e.g. I have:

```
 1_____16  
 2_____17  
 3_____18  
 4_____19  
 5_____20  
 6  
 7  
 8  
 9  
10  
11  
12  
13  
14  
15
```

Need change to: (Limit the No. of rows to 10)

```
 1_____11  
 2_____12  
 3_____13  
 4_____14  
 5_____15  
 6_____16  
 7_____17  
 8_____18  
 9_____19  
10_____20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as:

1. Format your report with multiple sections.
2. Split your details section into two sub-sections e.g. *Details **a*** and *Details **b***
3. Put all required report fields in *Details **a*** section only.
4. In *Section Expert* of *Details **b*** section, enable / check `Print at Bottom of Page`
5. Set suppression formula of *Details **b*** section as:

   ```
   if (RecordNumber mod 10) <> 0 then 
       true
   else
       false
   ```
6. Do **NOT** `Suppress Blank Section`, `New Page Before` or `New Page After` for *Details **b*** section

Above formula will print 10 records per column. You can replace 10 with your required number of records per column.

Comment: the format gets jumbled up if you have groups.. in order to fix this create a running total that counts every record and resets every group then use the {running total field (#Rtotal0)} instead of {RecordNumber} to fix (reset) your formatting after every group